# findContours not spotting extremely obvious contours in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to spot black rectangles using OpenCV in Python 2.7. I'm confused as to why my contour-finding code isn't spotting the black rectangle at the bottom of a PNG ([downloadable image, pre-grayscale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEXDi.jpg)):

[image]

Obviously, I want to spot the large black box. Here's my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

img = cv2.imread(f)
# grayscale
imgrey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# threshold and invert
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgrey, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# find contours, and draw red highlights around them
contours, h = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    mask = np.zeros(imgrey.shape, np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], 0, 255, -1)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x-2, y), (x+w+2, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 3)
cv2.imwrite(f.replace('.png', '-output.png'), img)
```

I get output that looks like this - it seems to be doing a brilliant job of spotting every possible contour *except* the one I'm interested in (note the lack of red line around the black box):

[image]

I can easily find ways to exclude the smaller contours (e.g. by looking at the mean colour value). But simply not spotting the contour of the black box, I'm not sure what to do about that.

What am I doing wrong?

For reference, this is what `thresh` looks like if I save it - the threshold seems to be working OK:

[image]

Comment: Could it be due to how it's connected to that long black line which links it with the whole black frame.

Comment: You could try Canny edge detector for that, I believe... OpenCV supports it.

Comment: @DanMašek very interesting, thanks! The code is working fine for most rectangles, this one was the exception so it could well be the connection... I'll try that...

Answer (score 0):

try Eroding and Dilating before `findContours` like below ( sorry i am not familiar with python)

```
erode(thresh,thresh,Mat(),Point(-1,-1),20);
dilate(thresh,thresh,Mat(),Point(-1,-1),20);
```

by this way you will get only one contour

[image]